# Socket.io updating multiple times

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, reactjs, socket.io

I included socket.io in a small React application and set up all of the listeners in "componentWillMount," as shown below.

```
componentWillMount() {  
    const socket = io();

    socket.on('update', function(newDataPoint) {
        console.log("Client updating!");
        this.setState({
            count: newDataPoint.count,
            temperature: newDataPoint.temperature,
            humidity: newDataPoint.humidity,
            pressure: newDataPoint.pressure
        }); 
    }.bind(this));      
}
```

On the server side, I have this:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    const pulse = setInterval(function() {
        console.log("From server."); 
        io.emit('update', {
            temperature: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 70),
            count: Math.floor(Math.random() * 300) + 5000, 
            humidity: Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 30,
            pressure: Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 29
        });
    }, 1000);

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        clearInterval(pulse);
    });
});
```

When I have just one instance of the app open it works fine, but with two it seems to be updating twice every second, then with three, three times etc. The console.logs show this too. I think it's because of new connections formed with the server, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Still pretty new to socket.io, so any help is welcomed. Thank you so much!

**Edit**: I fixed it by just deleting on connection, but how would I do things on a socket disconnect?

Comment: shouldn't the server side be using `socket.emit()`? You are creating a timer each time a client connects, so you emit data for each client with one more timer.4

Comment: If i wanted every connection to have the same data wouldn't it be io.emit? I thought socket.emit would have generated new data for each socket, but I may be wrong

Comment: then you must create the timer outside the connect function or make sure it is not created twice.

Comment: Got it, thank you! I'll rewrite it to do that.

Comment: You do nothing or you do a reference counter like I show in my sample. You don't care about different users, so you don't allocate anything on connect alas you don't return a thing on disconnect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a timer on each incoming connection. It is required to do this only once.

```
var connected = 0;

const pulse = setInterval(function() {
    console.log("From server."); 
    if(connected > 0) {
        io.emit('update', {
            temperature: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 70),
            count: Math.floor(Math.random() * 300) + 5000, 
            humidity: Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 30,
            pressure: Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 29
        }
    });

}, 1000);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    connected++;
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        connected--;
    });
});
```